# 'Collision2D' does not contain a definition for 'GameObject' (while using colliders)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I am using "GameObject" for reference without errors but when I use OnColissionEnter2D using the same GameObject, it gives me an error.**
I tried changing GameObject to gameObject on the Collision code and it worked but the code inside it doesn't work.
I also tried changing the public references to 'gameObjects" but then I got more errors to not change it.
**WHAT SHOULD I DO NOW???**
The Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsa7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es8TI.png)

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you are trying to do and what that code is supposed to do. Also don't post images of code, code is text

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Familiarize yourself with some basic concepts.  `GameObject` is a type, while `gameObject` is a field on some other types.  [Unity Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`. Also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I do not recommend coding in Notepad++.
Secondly, col.GameObject is not a thing, you are trying to get a Type from the collider. You have to use gameObject otherwise it's never going to work.
Last but not least, you are trying to check if the name of the collided object is Spawner, you are never using the Spawner you referenced at the top of your code.